# jquery ui dialog positioning with position option

Tags: jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-dialog

here is the html:

```
<div id="dlgAddStrategy" title="sss">
       ...
    </div>
```

and the js:

```
$("#dlgAddStrategy").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "top center", at: "top", of: window },
        buttons:
        {
           ..
        }
     }
```

it doesn't reposition. it is allways in the center of the entire window instead of it's center's top.

I also tried :

```
position: { my: "top center", at: "top", of: button}
```

and

```
position: { my: "center center", at: "top", of: window }
```